# How to change Appwidget Text's Gravity and Style

Tags: styles, android-appwidget, gravity

I was trying to set appwidget text gravity and style(italic,bold..) on code.

I tried

```
remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widgetText,"setGravity", Gravity.LEFT);
```

In AppWidget code

But this method did not work. it appears to widget "problem with loading widget"

```
remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.widgetText, Color.rgb(prefs.getInt("redFstatue", 255), prefs.getInt("greenFstatue", 255), prefs.getInt("blueFstatue", 255)));
```

While this color change code works fine.

is there any way to change text Style or Gravity on code?